# Proving $\forall s\in\mathbb{N},(\exists x \in\mathbb{N},s^2=3x)∨(\exists y\in\mathbb{N},s^2=3y-2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-writing, divisibility, proof-explanation

I'd like to prove the following statement:

> $\forall s\in\mathbb{N},(\exists x \in\mathbb{N},s^2=3x) \lor (\exists y\in\mathbb{N},s^2=3y-2)$

One approach which is most likely wrong that I have attempted was to split $s$ into odd and even numbers; $s=2k$ or $s=2k+1$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems wrong: what about $s=2$?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I'll fix that right away!

Comment: So what you want to prove now is that if you square any natural number the result is either $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$. Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Is it necessary for this proof?

Comment: No, it just makes it real easy. The key to doing this is, for any $s\in\Bbb N$, you can write $s=3k$ or $s=3k+1$ or $s=3k+2$ by the division algorithm. If this makes sense to you, then you're basically done: just square each case and see if you can write them in the form $3x$ or $3y-2$.

Comment: What is the division algorithm and would that be something I need to prove as well? Sorry, I'm still relatively new to proofs as a whole.

Comment: @Dave $2^2= 3\cdot 2-2$  [edit: oh, the statement has been modified since your comment; disreguard[

Comment: @GrahamKemp My original statement had it as $s$ instead of $s^2$, sorry about that.

Comment: The division algorithm is pretty basic, and I think it would be assumed known for this proof. Essentially, you're taking any integer $s$ and dividing it by $3$ to get a quotient $k$ and remainder $r$, i.e. you're writing $s=3k+r$ with $0\leq r<3$. So we must have $r=0,1,$ or $2$. I assume you know about remainders with integer division?

Comment: Haha, yes. And thanks for all the help! I think I'll be able to handle the rest.

Comment: Happy to help. When you complete your solution you're allowed to post it as an answer to your own question, and then you can accept the answer if you want (and if there's no other answer you want to accept) just to close off the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show

$\forall s\in\mathbb{N},(\exists x \in\mathbb{N},s^2=3x) \lor (\exists y\in\mathbb{N},s^2=3y-2)$

Note that every natural number $s$ is either $s= 3k$ or  $s=3k\pm 1$

In the first case let $$s^2=9k^2 = 3(3k^2)=3x$$ and in the second case $$s^2=9k^2\pm 6k+1$$ thus $$ s^2+2=9k^2\pm 6k+3=3(3k^2 \pm 2k+1)=3y$$

that is $s^2 =3y-2$

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove the statement, since it's false.  You have tried to split the natural numbers into those divisible by 3 and those congruent to 1 (same as -2) mod 3, but you've left out those congruent to 2 mod 3.  Thus, s = 2, 5, 8, etc., are all counter-examples to your statement.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that, I made an edit just now.

Answer (score 0):

The statement  $$   \forall s\in\mathbb{N},(\exists x \in\mathbb{N},s=3x) \lor (\exists y\in\mathbb{N},s=3y-2) $$                   is not true.

For example for  $s=5$ you can not find an $x\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $5=3x$ nore you can find a  $y\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $5=3y-2$

Comment: This proof works for your unedited version.